# What's wrong with this GStreamer pipeline?

Tags: gstreamer, pipeline

I'm sure I've had this pipeline working on an earlier Ubuntu system I had set up (formatted for readability):

```
playbin
    uri=rtspt://user:pswd@192.168.xxx.yyy/ch1/main
    video-sink='videoconvert
                ! videoflip method=counterclockwise
                ! fpsdisplaysink'
```

Yet, when I try to use it within my program, I get:

```
Missing element: H.264 (Main Profile) decoder
WARNING: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0:
    No decoder available for type 'video/x-h264,
    stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au,
    codec_data=(buffer)014d001fffe10017674d001f9a6602802dff35010101400000fa000030d40101000468ee3c80,
    level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)main, width=(int)1280,
    height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)0/1, parsed=(boolean)true'.

Additional debug info:
    gsturidecodebin.c(938): unknown_type_cb ():
        /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0
```

Now I'm pretty certain I *have* an H264 decoder installed and indeed the gstreamer plugins `autogen.sh/configure` correctly recognised the fact. Installed packages are `h264enc`, `libx264-142`, `libx264-dev` and `x264`.

It does exactly the same thing if I use the more "acceptable" `autovideosink` in place of `fpsdisplaysink`, or if I try to play the RTSP stream with `gst-play-1.0`. However, it works if I use the test pattern source `videotestsrc`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like gstreamer cannot find a suitable plugin for decoding H264. Either you do not have an H264 decoder element installed, or gstreamer is looking in the wrong path for your elements.

First, try running `gst-inspect-1.0`. This should output a long list of all the elements gstreamer has detected.

- If this doesn't return any elements, you probably need to set the GST_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable to point to the directory where your plugins are installed. [Running Gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html) - This link should help.
- If it DOES return many elements, run `gst-inspect-1.0 avdec_h264` to verify that you have the H264 decoder element.

Comment: Inspection shows that all the plugins are available so I shouldn't need the plugin path. I have no `avdec_h264` but I believe `x264` does the decoding and it's listed in inspect output and in `/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstx264.so`.

Comment: As far as I know there is no x264 decoder, only an encoder, see [here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Where-can-I-get-x264enc-x264dec-rtph264pay-and-depay-td2553663.html). You will need to install/compile gst-libav to get the avdec_h264 element for decoding H264.

Comment: gst-libav was indeed what I was also missing. To install it on Ubuntu 16.04 I executed: `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav`

Comment: GST_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/ gst-inspect-1.0 avdec_h264 and it is still "not found"

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the following:

1. `sudo apt-get install h264enc`
2. `sudo apt-get install --yes libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio`
3. `sudo apt-get install --yes libgirepository1.0-dev libgstrtspserver-1.0 libgstreamer1.0-dev`

if you face broken packages run this command: `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and then execute the abovementioned steps.